# Randomly select a proportion of files from a given directory

Tags: linux, command-line, files, mv

There are about 10000 files under a given directory. Are there any command that can help me randomly pick 1000 files from it and put them into another directory. The picked files should be removed from the original directory.

Comment: See also [List X random files from a directory](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48476)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `shuf`, it will easily let you do what you want, provided that no filename has a newline character in it, and there are no subdirectories:

```
mapfile -t sample < <(shuf -n 1000 -e given_directory/*)
mv "${sample[@]}" other_directory
```

If there are subdirectories, you could get the list of files by using `find` instead of the glob. Or you could oversample and filter. `find` will also help you deal with files which could have newlines in their names (which is really a bad idea, but that doesn't necessarily mean that you can ignore the possibility), since you can use the `-print0` action combined with the `-z` flag to `shuf`. For example,

```
find given_directory -type f -print0 |
shuf -z -n 1000 |
xargs -0 mv -t other_directory
```

`mv -t` is a (very useful) Gnu extension which lets you provide the destination directory at the beginning of the command line, which works nicely with the `xargs`/`find -exec` model of putting multiple arguments at the end of the command line.