# Pick randomly 30% of the files in a folder

Tags: bash, pipe, ls

I have a number of folders, each with audio files in it. I want to pick out 30% of each of this files and cut them (not copy) to another folder. I can see [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48476/list-x-random-files-from-a-directory/48477#48477) which can help me do this given that I know the number of files in each folder. Sadly the number may change and I want a single piped bash line that can do this. Is this possible? How do I choose 30% of the files and cut them to another folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `bash` 4.4+ and on a GNU system, you can do:

```
readarray -td '' files < <(
  shopt -s nullglob dotglob
  printf '%s\0' * | sort -Rz
)
```

to populate the `$files` array with a shuffled list of all the files in the current directory.

Then you can move 30% of them with something like:

```
echo mv -- "${files[@]:0:${#files[@]}*30/100}" /target/directory/
```

(remove the `echo` when you're satisfied it's going to do what you want).

The equivalent in the `zsh` shell could be something like:

```
files=(*(NDnoe['REPLY=$RANDOM']))
echo mv -- $files[1,$#files*30/100] /target/directory/
```

That's the same approach, only terser and not needing external utilities. Translation:

- `shopt -s nullglob` -> `N` glob qualifier (create an empty array when there's no file).
- `shopt -s dotglob` -> `D` glob qualifier (do not exclude files whose name start with a dot).
- GNU `sort -Rz`: `noe['REPLY=$RANDOM']` (shuffle the list by sorting using a random order).
- `${array[@]:offset:length}` -> `$array[first,last]` (zsh now also supports the Korn shell syntax, but I find the zsh one more legible).
- With `bash` we use NUL delimited records (`-d ''`/`-z`/`\0`) to be able to deal with arbitrary file names. It's not needed in `zsh` as the list is never transformed to a single string/stream.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls | shuf -n $(( $(ls | wc -l) *  30 / 100))
```

All you need to do is to find the number of files and the percentage separately. 
For this

1. `$(ls | wc -l)` will first calculate the number of files in the directory
2. `$(( x * 30 /100))` will do the arithmetic operation of finding the 30% of that number
3. Finally , that number is passed to `shuf -n` to get a random list of files

Comment: `ls | wc -l` will count the number of lines returned from `ls`, which may be the same as the number of files if no filename contains any newlines. Use `set -- *; echo "$#"` to count the number of names that `*` expands to instead.

Comment: or you can use `ls -b` instead