# How to move 15 files from a folder containing thousands?

Tags: files, mv

I have a directory with thousands of video file. How can I move 15 of the files (video.mp4) to another location.

Comment: Do you know their names?

Comment: Or, if it is just 15, try `ls | head -15` and `mv` those files to the other location.

Comment: no just move name It does not matter to me

Comment: With zsh, this may help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48486/117549

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find a script and mod it for this work

```
#!/bin/bash
c=1; d=1; mkdir -p NEWDIR_${d}
for mpeg_file in *.mp4
do
if [ $c -eq 15 ]
then
d=$(( d + 1 )); c=0; mkdir -p NEWDIR_${d}
fi
mv "$mpeg_file" NEWDIR_${d}/
c=$(( c + 1 ))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `mv` tag already gives the solution.  `man mv` states:

```
Name: mv - move (rename) files
Synopsis:
    mv [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
    mv [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
    mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...

Description: 
Rename SOURCE to DEST, or move SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.
<...>
```

If you use `ls` to find 15 file names, you can move them with `mv`.